# Broadcast UDP Message from Raspberry Pi to other subnet in the LAN

Tags: networking, mono

I have created two C# application to send a UDP command to broadcast IP and receive the message. I can send the broadcast message from my windows system to Raspberry Pi and receive the message in my application. But it failed when I tried to send from Raspberry Pi to Windows. Anybody know why its not sending from raspberry pi to Windows.

I tried static IP instead of broadcast IP then the application worked fine. But the application did not worked using broadcast IP in RPi. I checked the network packets using wireshark, not getting the message in my windows.

Comment: Maybe your windows firewall is blocking the incoming message? Can another windows with the APP send and receive from windows? (on another subnet)

Comment: You need to diagnose this with a packet sniffer such as **wireshark** to determine exactly what is happening.  Otherwise all people can do is throw out random guesses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this using wireshark.

Comment: If wireshark on windows doesn't show the packets at all, then presumably there is something wrong with your application.  Just because it works on one system does not mean it is bug free and therefore must work everywhere else.   You might try `tshark` (or wireshark) on the pi at the same time to check this, but note that questions about debugging C# code  belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).   The significant difference here is not the pi, it's the operating system (presumably some flavor of linux).